# Symfony 5 and Doctrine, can't find a way to fetch results with 3 related entities

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

EDIT : This question has been updated, I'm good now, thanks to chat with @Jakumi.

I have multiple websites running on the same Symfony 5 installation.
This websites show videos based on video categories, but they share the same videos database.
I have an Entity called "Video", "Website" and one last called "Category" :

Entity/Video.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="videos")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"priority" = "DESC"})
*/
private $category;
```

Entity/Category.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Video::class, mappedBy="category")
*/
private $videos;
```

Entity/Website.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="websites")
*/
private $categories;
```

For example I have 4 videos and their categories.

```
video
id  title
1  | "Lol Pro PLayer"
2  | "Lol Casual Player"
3  | "Counter Strike Casual Player"
4  | "Counter Strike Pro Player"


website
id | title
1  | "LOL PROS"
2  | "CS Gamers"
3  | "CS Pro Gamers"


category
id | title
1  | "Pro"
2  | "League of Legend"
3  | "Counter Strike"


video_category
video_id | category_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 2
3        | 3
4        | 1
4        | 3


website_category
website_id | category_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 3
3          | 1
3          | 2
```

Currently, I'm able to get videos like this (dirty way), I've hardcoded the website categories IDs in the first time.

**Website 1 should only show videos that are in both categories "Pro" and "League of Legends" (It can have like 3 or 4 categories for each website), so in he example, only the video called "Lol Pro Player" (id : 1)**

App\Repository\VideoRepository.php

```
public function findWebsiteVideos($website)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    return $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT v
        FROM App\Entity\Video v
        WHERE v.id IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT v_1.id
            FROM App\Entity\Video v_1
            JOIN v_1.category vc_1
            WHERE vc_1.id = 408
        )
        AND v.id IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT v_2.id
            FROM App\Entity\Video v_2
            JOIN v_2.category vc_2
            WHERE vc_2.id = 454
        )
        AND v.id IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT v_3.id
            FROM App\Entity\Video v_3
            JOIN v_3.category vc_3
            WHERE vc_3.id = 504
        )
        ORDER BY v.id ASC'
    );
}
```

I'm trying to find the right DQL to avoid dirty work, I need to mention that I can't use "HAVING" with the current pagination system.

Comment: Why are you looking for a SQL query to be used in Doctrine? Why not use repositories or DQL?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my question to make it more clear. Right now, I don't understand how I can write the DQL about this query. After being able to write this one, I'll have to work to write the one where I don't need to hardcode website categories IDs. This code works currently, but I want to write the "good practice" code.

Comment: don't know what you'r referring to as "dirty work", hard to answer when it's the objective to avoid it ;o)

Comment: I mean I'm currently doing a loop on the website categories to create the SQL query where I think it might be done nicely with DQL. :/

Comment: I hope you're aware, that your query already *is* DQL and you might be referring to the query-builder instead. I'm pretty certain you might use `HAVING` in the sub-query which might help a lot. ;o)

Comment: Thank for your comment, I wasn't aware of this (DQL), you're right, it's the queryBuilder, I'll try to find way. I can't use HAVING clause currently due to the pagination system.

Comment: can you tell us which pagination system that is? however, imho the workarounds won't be more performant or more "beautiful" ...

Comment: The pagination use KnpPaginatorBundle :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224886/discussion-between-jakumi-and-elex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do in the video repository:

```
$qb->createQueryBuilder(‘v’);
 $qb->join(‘v.category’, ‘c’)
   ->join(‘c.websites, ‘w’)
   ->where($qb->expr()->eq(‘w.id’, ‘:website’))
   ->setParameter(‘website’, $your_website_id)
   ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Based on the edit, you will need to make two queries /it’s faster that way/

First fetch the website categories and the query for videos based on these categories

Comment: Thank you for your help, yes, I've made one like this (not simple as this one, I feel dumb) , this is close to working, but it gives videos that don't have "all the required categories". It fetch video "Lol Casual Player" (id:2) on the website "LOL Pros" (id:1) where website categories are "Pro" and "League of Legend", I should only have video 1. That's my issue from the beginning.

Comment: Actually based on your schema 1- the query should return 3 videos IDs 1,2 and 4 because the website 1 is assigned to categories 1 and 2 which contain these 3 videos. Video 2 shows as result because it is in category 2 which the website 1 is assigned to...

Comment: Yes, because it's doing something like a OR on website categories, but I want a AND, and that's something I don't find in DQL. Videos from Website 1 ("Pro", "League of Legends") should get only videos that are in both "Pro" AND "League Of Legends" cats, not only in cat "Pro" OR in cat "League of Legends". In pure SQL, it's ok, but in DQL, it's like "OR" in website categories.